# Removing parameters refactoring

Tags: c#, rubberduck

After the [Reorder Parameters](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91221/reordering-method-parameters) refactoring, I implemented a Remove Parameters refactoring (no, it didn't take this long, just been busy).  Also, we completely refactored all the refactorings and implemented a couple interfaces for them all, which you can find [here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/tree/next/RetailCoder.VBE/Refactorings); for reference, the Remove refactoring code is found [here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/tree/next/RetailCoder.VBE/Refactorings/RemoveParameters), and the view is [here](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/RetailCoder.VBE/UI/Refactorings/RemoveParametersDialog.cs).

Namespace for all these classes are `Rubberduck.Refactorings.RemoveParameters`.

This is the model (`RemoveParametersModel`):

```
private readonly VBProjectParseResult _parseResult;
public VBProjectParseResult ParseResult { get { return _parseResult; } }

private readonly Declarations _declarations;
public Declarations Declarations { get { return _declarations; } }

public Declaration TargetDeclaration { get; private set; }
public List<Parameter> Parameters { get; set; }

public RemoveParametersModel(VBProjectParseResult parseResult, QualifiedSelection selection)
{
    _parseResult = parseResult;
    _declarations = parseResult.Declarations;

    AcquireTarget(selection);

    Parameters = new List<Parameter>();
    LoadParameters();
}

private void AcquireTarget(QualifiedSelection selection)
{
    TargetDeclaration = FindTarget(selection, ValidDeclarationTypes);
    TargetDeclaration = PromptIfTargetImplementsInterface();
    TargetDeclaration = GetGetter();
}

private void LoadParameters()
{
    Parameters.Clear();

    var index = 0;
    Parameters = GetParameters(TargetDeclaration).Select(arg => new Parameter(arg, index++)).ToList();
}

private IEnumerable<Declaration> GetParameters(Declaration method)
{
    return Declarations.Items
                      .Where(d => d.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Parameter
                               && d.ComponentName == method.ComponentName
                               && d.Project.Equals(method.Project)
                               && method.Context.Start.Line <= d.Selection.StartLine
                               && method.Context.Stop.Line >= d.Selection.EndLine
                               && !(method.Context.Start.Column > d.Selection.StartColumn && method.Context.Start.Line == d.Selection.StartLine)
                               && !(method.Context.Stop.Column < d.Selection.EndColumn && method.Context.Stop.Line == d.Selection.EndLine))
                      .OrderBy(item => item.Selection.StartLine)
                      .ThenBy(item => item.Selection.StartColumn);
}

public static readonly DeclarationType[] ValidDeclarationTypes =
{
    DeclarationType.Event,
    DeclarationType.Function,
    DeclarationType.Procedure,
    DeclarationType.PropertyGet,
    DeclarationType.PropertyLet,
    DeclarationType.PropertySet
};

public Declaration FindTarget(QualifiedSelection selection, DeclarationType[] validDeclarationTypes)
{
    var target = Declarations.Items
        .Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn)
        .FirstOrDefault(item => IsSelectedDeclaration(selection, item)
                                || IsSelectedReference(selection, item));

    if (target != null && validDeclarationTypes.Contains(target.DeclarationType))
    {
        return target;
    }

    target = null;

    var targets = Declarations.Items
        .Where(item => !item.IsBuiltIn
                       && item.ComponentName == selection.QualifiedName.ComponentName
                       && validDeclarationTypes.Contains(item.DeclarationType));

    var currentSelection = new Selection(0, 0, int.MaxValue, int.MaxValue);

    foreach (var declaration in targets)
    {
        var declarationSelection = new Selection(declaration.Context.Start.Line,
            declaration.Context.Start.Column,
            declaration.Context.Stop.Line,
            declaration.Context.Stop.Column);

        if (currentSelection.Contains(declarationSelection) &&
            declarationSelection.Contains(selection.Selection))
        {
            target = declaration;
            currentSelection = declarationSelection;
        }

        foreach (var reference in declaration.References)
        {
            var proc = (dynamic) reference.Context.Parent;
            VBAParser.ArgsCallContext paramList;

            // This is to prevent throws when this statement fails:
            // (VBAParser.ArgsCallContext)proc.argsCall();
            try
            {
                paramList = (VBAParser.ArgsCallContext) proc.argsCall();
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (paramList == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var referenceSelection = new Selection(paramList.Start.Line,
                paramList.Start.Column,
                paramList.Stop.Line,
                paramList.Stop.Column + paramList.Stop.Text.Length + 1);

            if (currentSelection.Contains(declarationSelection) &&
                referenceSelection.Contains(selection.Selection))
            {
                target = reference.Declaration;
                currentSelection = referenceSelection;
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}

private Declaration PromptIfTargetImplementsInterface()
{
    var declaration = TargetDeclaration;
    var interfaceImplementation = Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers().SingleOrDefault(m => m.Equals(declaration));
    if (declaration == null || interfaceImplementation == null)
    {
        return declaration;
    }

    var interfaceMember = Declarations.FindInterfaceMember(interfaceImplementation);
    var message = string.Format(RubberduckUI.Refactoring_TargetIsInterfaceMemberImplementation, declaration.IdentifierName, interfaceMember.ComponentName, interfaceMember.IdentifierName);

    var confirm = MessageBox.Show(message, RubberduckUI.ReorderParamsDialog_TitleText, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    return confirm == DialogResult.No ? null : interfaceMember;
}

private bool IsSelectedReference(QualifiedSelection selection, Declaration declaration)
{
    return declaration.References.Any(r =>
        r.QualifiedModuleName == selection.QualifiedName &&
        r.Selection.ContainsFirstCharacter(selection.Selection));
}

private bool IsSelectedDeclaration(QualifiedSelection selection, Declaration declaration)
{
    return declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName == selection.QualifiedName
           && (declaration.Selection.ContainsFirstCharacter(selection.Selection));
}

private Declaration GetGetter()
{
    if (TargetDeclaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.PropertyLet &&
        TargetDeclaration.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.PropertySet)
    {
        return TargetDeclaration;
    }

    var getter = _declarations.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Scope == TargetDeclaration.Scope &&
                                  item.IdentifierName == TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName &&
                                  item.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertyGet);

    return getter ?? TargetDeclaration;
}
```

This is the actual refactoring (`RemoveParametersRefactoring`):

```
private readonly IRefactoringPresenterFactory<RemoveParametersPresenter> _factory;
private RemoveParametersModel _model;

public RemoveParametersRefactoring(IRefactoringPresenterFactory<RemoveParametersPresenter> factory)
{
    _factory = factory;
}

public void Refactor()
{
    var presenter = _factory.Create();
    if (presenter == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    _model = presenter.Show();
    if (_model == null || !_model.Parameters.Any(item => item.IsRemoved))
    {
        return;
    }

    RemoveParameters();
}

public void Refactor(QualifiedSelection target)
{
    target.Select();
    Refactor();
}

public void Refactor(Declaration target)
{
    if (!RemoveParametersModel.ValidDeclarationTypes.Contains(target.DeclarationType) && target.DeclarationType != DeclarationType.Parameter)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid declaration type");
    }

    target.QualifiedSelection.Select();
    Refactor();
}

public void QuickFix(VBProjectParseResult parseResult, QualifiedSelection selection)
{
    _model = new RemoveParametersModel(parseResult, selection);
    var target = _model.FindTarget(selection, new[] { DeclarationType.Parameter });

    // ReSharper disable once PossibleUnintendedReferenceComparison
    _model.Parameters.Find(param => param.Declaration == target).IsRemoved = true;
    RemoveParameters();
}

private void RemoveParameters()
{
    if (_model.TargetDeclaration == null) { throw new NullReferenceException("Parameter is null."); }

    AdjustReferences(_model.TargetDeclaration.References.OrderByDescending(item => item.Selection.StartLine), _model.TargetDeclaration);
    AdjustSignatures();
}

private void AdjustReferences(IEnumerable<IdentifierReference> references, Declaration method)
{
    foreach (var reference in references.Where(item => item.Context != method.Context))
    {
        var proc = (dynamic)reference.Context.Parent;
        var module = reference.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;
        VBAParser.ArgsCallContext paramList;

        // This is to prevent throws when this statement fails:
        // (VBAParser.ArgsCallContext)proc.argsCall();
        try { paramList = (VBAParser.ArgsCallContext)proc.argsCall(); }
        catch { continue; }

        if (paramList == null) { continue; }

        RemoveCallParameter(paramList, module);
    }
}

private void RemoveCallParameter(VBAParser.ArgsCallContext paramList, CodeModule module)
{
    var paramNames = paramList.argCall().Select(arg => arg.GetText()).ToList();
    var lineCount = paramList.Stop.Line - paramList.Start.Line + 1; // adjust for total line count

    var newContent = module.Lines[paramList.Start.Line, lineCount].Replace(" _", "").RemoveExtraSpaces();
    var currentStringIndex = 0;

    foreach (
        var param in
            _model.Parameters.Where(item => item.IsRemoved && item.Index < paramNames.Count)
                .Select(item => item.Declaration))
    {
        var paramIndex = _model.Parameters.FindIndex(item => item.Declaration.Context.GetText() == param.Context.GetText()); 
        if (paramIndex >= paramNames.Count) { return; }

        do
        {
            var paramToRemoveName = paramNames.ElementAt(0).Contains(":=")
                ? paramNames.Find(item => item.Contains(param.IdentifierName + ":="))
                : paramNames.ElementAt(paramIndex);

            if (paramToRemoveName == null || !newContent.Contains(paramToRemoveName))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var valueToRemove = paramToRemoveName != paramNames.Last()
                ? paramToRemoveName + ","
                : paramToRemoveName;

            var parameterStringIndex = newContent.IndexOf(valueToRemove, currentStringIndex, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (parameterStringIndex <= -1) { continue; }

            newContent = newContent.Remove(parameterStringIndex, valueToRemove.Length);

            currentStringIndex = parameterStringIndex;

            if (paramToRemoveName == paramNames.Last() && newContent.LastIndexOf(',') != -1)
            {
                newContent = newContent.Remove(newContent.LastIndexOf(','), 1);
            }
        } while (paramIndex >= _model.Parameters.Count - 1 && ++paramIndex < paramNames.Count &&
                 newContent.Contains(paramNames.ElementAt(paramIndex)));
    }

    module.ReplaceLine(paramList.Start.Line, newContent);
    module.DeleteLines(paramList.Start.Line + 1, lineCount - 1);
}

private string GetOldSignature(Declaration target)
{
    var targetModule = _model.ParseResult.ComponentParseResults.SingleOrDefault(m => m.QualifiedName == target.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName);
    if (targetModule == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var rewriter = targetModule.GetRewriter();

    var context = target.Context;
    var firstTokenIndex = context.Start.TokenIndex;
    var lastTokenIndex = -1; // will blow up if this code runs for any context other than below

    var subStmtContext = context as VBAParser.SubStmtContext;
    if (subStmtContext != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = subStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
    }

    var functionStmtContext = context as VBAParser.FunctionStmtContext;
    if (functionStmtContext != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = functionStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null
            ? functionStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex
            : functionStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
    }

    var propertyGetStmtContext = context as VBAParser.PropertyGetStmtContext;
    if (propertyGetStmtContext != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = propertyGetStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null
            ? propertyGetStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex
            : propertyGetStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
    }

    var propertyLetStmtContext = context as VBAParser.PropertyLetStmtContext;
    if (propertyLetStmtContext != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = propertyLetStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
    }

    var propertySetStmtContext = context as VBAParser.PropertySetStmtContext;
    if (propertySetStmtContext != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = propertySetStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
    }

    var declareStmtContext = context as VBAParser.DeclareStmtContext;
    if (declareStmtContext != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.STRINGLITERAL().Last().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        if (declareStmtContext.argList() != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
        }
        if (declareStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null)
        {
            lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex;
        }
    }

    var eventStmtContext = context as VBAParser.EventStmtContext;
    if (eventStmtContext != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = eventStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
    }

    return rewriter.GetText(new Interval(firstTokenIndex, lastTokenIndex));
}

private string ReplaceCommas(string signature, int indexParamRemoved)
{
    if (signature.Count(c => c == ',') > indexParamRemoved) { indexParamRemoved++; }

    for (int i = 0, commaCounter = 0; i < signature.Length && indexParamRemoved != 0; i++)
    {
        if (signature.ElementAt(i) == ',')
        {
            commaCounter++;
        }

        if (commaCounter == indexParamRemoved)
        {
            return signature.Remove(i, 1);
        }
    }

    return signature;
}

private void AdjustSignatures()
{
    var proc = (dynamic)_model.TargetDeclaration.Context;
    var paramList = (VBAParser.ArgListContext)proc.argList();
    var module = _model.TargetDeclaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;

    // if we are adjusting a property getter, check if we need to adjust the letter/setter too
    if (_model.TargetDeclaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertyGet)
    {
        var setter = GetLetterOrSetter(_model.TargetDeclaration, DeclarationType.PropertySet);
        if (setter != null)
        {
            AdjustSignatures(setter);
        }

        var letter = GetLetterOrSetter(_model.TargetDeclaration, DeclarationType.PropertyLet);
        if (letter != null)
        {
            AdjustSignatures(letter);
        }
    }

    RemoveSignatureParameters(_model.TargetDeclaration, paramList, module);

    foreach (var withEvents in _model.Declarations.Items.Where(item => item.IsWithEvents && item.AsTypeName == _model.TargetDeclaration.ComponentName))
    {
        foreach (var reference in _model.Declarations.FindEventProcedures(withEvents))
        {
            AdjustReferences(reference.References.OrderByDescending(item => item.Selection.StartLine), reference);
            AdjustSignatures(reference);
        }
    }

    var interfaceImplementations = _model.Declarations.FindInterfaceImplementationMembers()
                                                .Where(item => item.Project.Equals(_model.TargetDeclaration.Project) &&
                                                       item.IdentifierName == _model.TargetDeclaration.ComponentName + "_" + _model.TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName);
    foreach (var interfaceImplentation in interfaceImplementations)
    {
        AdjustReferences(interfaceImplentation.References.OrderByDescending(item => item.Selection.StartLine), interfaceImplentation);
        AdjustSignatures(interfaceImplentation);
    }
}

private Declaration GetLetterOrSetter(Declaration declaration, DeclarationType declarationType)
{
    return _model.Declarations.Items.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Scope == declaration.Scope &&
                      item.IdentifierName == declaration.IdentifierName &&
                      item.DeclarationType == declarationType);
}

private void AdjustSignatures(Declaration declaration)
{
    var proc = (dynamic)declaration.Context.Parent;
    var module = declaration.QualifiedName.QualifiedModuleName.Component.CodeModule;
    VBAParser.ArgListContext paramList;

    if (declaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertySet ||
        declaration.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.PropertyLet)
    {
        paramList = (VBAParser.ArgListContext)proc.children[0].argList();
    }
    else
    {
        paramList = (VBAParser.ArgListContext)proc.subStmt().argList();
    }

    RemoveSignatureParameters(declaration, paramList, module);
}

private void RemoveSignatureParameters(Declaration target, VBAParser.ArgListContext paramList, CodeModule module)
{
    var paramNames = paramList.arg();

    var paramsRemoved = _model.Parameters.Where(item => item.IsRemoved).ToList();
    var signature = GetOldSignature(target);

    foreach (var param in paramsRemoved)
    {
        try
        {
            signature = ReplaceCommas(signature.Replace(paramNames.ElementAt(param.Index).GetText(), ""), _model.Parameters.FindIndex(item => item == param) - paramsRemoved.FindIndex(item => item == param));
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
        }
    }
    var lineNum = paramList.GetSelection().LineCount;

    module.ReplaceLine(paramList.Start.Line, signature);
    module.DeleteLines(paramList.Start.Line + 1, lineNum - 1);
}
```

And this is the presenter (`RemoveParametersPresenter`):

```
private readonly IRemoveParametersView _view;
private readonly RemoveParametersModel _model;

public RemoveParametersPresenter(IRemoveParametersView view, RemoveParametersModel model)
{
    _view = view;
    _model = model;
}

public RemoveParametersModel Show()
{
    if (_model.Parameters.Count == 0)
    {
        var message = string.Format(RubberduckUI.RemovePresenter_NoParametersError, _model.TargetDeclaration.IdentifierName);
        MessageBox.Show(message, RubberduckUI.RemoveParamsDialog_TitleText, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        return null;
    }

    if (_model.Parameters.Count == 1)
    {
        _model.Parameters[0].IsRemoved = true;
        return _model;
    }

    _view.Parameters = _model.Parameters;
    _view.InitializeParameterGrid();

    if (_view.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        return null;
    }

    _model.Parameters = _view.Parameters;
    return _model;
}
```

As always, I welcome all comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's quite a lot to review.
And it looks mostly pretty nice.
I only have some pretty minor nitpicks.

---

> ```
>     if (declareStmtContext.argList() != null)
>     {
>         lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
>     }
>     if (declareStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null)
>     {
>         lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex;
>     }
> ```

I'm not a big fan of reassigning values.
If the second condition is true,
`lastTokenIndex` will be overwritten,
and it will have been pointless.
This should be equivalent,
with no reassignment and no unnecessary statements:

```
    if (declareStmtContext.asTypeClause() != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.asTypeClause().Stop.TokenIndex;
    }
    else if (declareStmtContext.argList() != null)
    {
        lastTokenIndex = declareStmtContext.argList().RPAREN().Symbol.TokenIndex;
    }
```

That is, I just moved the second condition up,
and chained the two conditions with `else if`.

---

When the statement in the `foreach` is so long as here:

> ```
> foreach (
>     var param in
>         _model.Parameters.Where(item => item.IsRemoved && item.Index < paramNames.Count)
>             .Select(item => item.Declaration))
> {
> ```

I'd recommend to extract the `_model.Parameters.Where...` part into a local variable before the loop, like this:

```
var removedDeclarations =
    _model.Parameters
    .Where(item => item.IsRemoved && item.Index < paramNames.Count)
    .Select(item => item.Declaration)

foreach (var param in removedDeclarations) { ... }
```

Note that this has the drawback that it exposes `removedDeclarations` available outside the scope of the `foreach`.
So there's a trade-off, I let you decide the lesser evil.

Another alternative is to extract the query to a method.
That way you could avoid exposing a local variable outside the `foreach`,
something along the lines of:

```
foreach (var param in GetRemovedDeclarations(...)) { ... }
```

---

Some boolean conditions are really complex, for example:

> ```
> return Declarations.Items
>                   .Where(d => d.DeclarationType == DeclarationType.Parameter
>                            && d.ComponentName == method.ComponentName
>                            && d.Project.Equals(method.Project)
>                            && method.Context.Start.Line <= d.Selection.StartLine
>                            && method.Context.Stop.Line >= d.Selection.EndLine
>                            && !(method.Context.Start.Column > d.Selection.StartColumn && method.Context.Start.Line ==  d.Selection.StartLine)
>                            && !(method.Context.Stop.Column < d.Selection.EndColumn && method.Context.Stop.Line == d.Selection.EndLine))
> ```

It might be a good idea to extract to a function with a descriptive name.

Comment: Whoops, that last Boolean condition needs to be updated to use `Selection.Contains()`.  Thanks for the review.

Comment: ++ Extracting a method would be the preferred solution.

Comment: @RubberDuck There already is a method - I was re-inventing the wheel here.